# Ajax call to a page shows both success and error message

Tags: javascript, ajax

I tried to make an ajax call to **successtext.html** which is in my computer,  but I can see both success and error messages in my browser's console. This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).ready()=>{
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "successtext.html",
                    success : console.log("success"),
                    error : console.log("error")
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: There are issues in your code, one the goes to syntax (=>) after window ready and success and errors are callbacks so write those console logs in to them. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the expression you assign to `success` and `error` needs to be a **function**.

You are (immediately) calling `console.log()` and assigning its return value.

```
success: () => console.log("success"),
error: () => console.log("error")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
...        
success : function() {
   console.log("success");
},
error : function() {
   console.log("error");
}
...
```